Langevin SDE, gradient with respect to intial condition, and an associated quadratic form
I'm considering the following Langevin SDE, for $X_t \in \mathbb{R}^d$:
$$dX_t^y=-\nabla V(X_t^y) dt + \sqrt{2} dB_t, \quad X_0^y = y \in \mathbb{R}^d.$$ Here, the superscript of $y$ makes explicit the initial condition. I won't impose any conditions $V: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ for now, other than that it is twice continuously differentiable. Now, I want to study the object $\nabla_y X_t^y$, which, for a fixed $t$, is the gradient of $X_t$ with respect to the starting location $y$. One can derive (e.g., using Theorem 39 of Chapter V here) that we have $$\nabla_y X_t^y = I_d - \int_0^t \rm{Hess}(V)(X_s^y)\cdot \nabla_y  X_s^y ds \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}.$$
Ultimately, I want to understand the quadratic form, for unit vectors $u \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $$u^T \cdot \left( \nabla_y X_t^y\right)^T \left(\rm{Hess}(V)(X_t^y) \right)\left( \nabla_y X_t^y\right) \cdot u.$$ Ideally, I would like an upper bound on the operator norm of this matrix (could be a bound in the $\infty$ norm, or potentially just a high-probability bound, or a bound in expectation, I am not sure yet), and want to explore what conditions on $V$ would lead to these bounds. For example, if we assume that $\rm{Hess}(V)$ has eigenvalues lower bounded by $\epsilon,$ then this is more or less straightforward, but I think that condition is unsatisfying.
Any thoughts would be great!
